# php memcache orm caching and purging

Tags: php, caching, orm, memcached, phalcon

I'd like to implement a memcache based caching for my ORM. Let's assume, that I have 2 methods on my User-Model to fetch the same set of data:

```
 + findById(1234);
 + findByUsername('roman');
```

different queries, same resultset. Now both resultsets are cached by memcache under different keys (containing mysql where statements to separate them). pretty bad when it comes to purging after editing the user model. I have to purge 2 keys which I'm not able to know, because the keys are looking like this:

```
+ findById       -> user_id_1234_visible_true_enabled_true (and so on)
+ findByUsername -> user_username_roman_visible_true_enabled_true (and so on)
```

the question is now, how can I purge both keys.

the only solution I've found so far is to split the findByUsername in 2 mysql calls:

```
1. findIdByUsername()
2. get id from resultset
3. findById(withFetchedId)
4. cache findById resultset
```

I hope you have a hint for me with another solution I can come up with.
thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to override `Model::find()` and `Model::findFirst()` on that particular model in manner as it is described in [ORM Cache Manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/models-cache.html#overriding-find-findfirst). But I think it does not 100% solve your problem unless:

**a)** depending on how many users you have in DB I would probably cache full collection of `{login: id}` - small/medium CRM case

**b)** or cache them for some time once their happen to be needed:

```
1. if userId not in cache, fetch from findIdByUsername() and cache it under username
2. get userId from cache based on username
3. findById()
```

so in real you will ask from time to time a query for userId, having core functionality based on `getUserById()` - whats quite proper approach.